# Reconstruction of Digital Signal using the sinc Function

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, sampling, nyquist

I am trying to reconstruct the signal cos(2*pi*300e6) at the sampling frequency 800e6 using the sinc function in MATLAB. When I type in the following code, I'm instead getting something very noisy--not what I am looking for. What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance!

Code:

```
F1 = 300e6;
Fs = 800e6;
tmin = 0;
tmax = 10/F1;
t = tmin:1e-12:tmax;
x1 = cos(2*pi*F1*t);
Ts = 1/Fs;
ts = tmin:Ts:tmax;
x1resampled = cos(2*pi*F1*ts);
x1reconstructed = zeros(1,length(t)); %preallocating for speed
samples = length(ts);
for i = 1:1:length(t)
    for n = 1:1:samples
        x1reconstructed(i) = sum(x1resampled(n)*sinc(pi*(t(i)-n*Ts)/Ts));
    end
end
figure(1)
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(t,x1)
hold on
stem(ts,x1resampled)
subplot(2,1,2)
plot(t,x1reconstructed)
```

Comment: So did any of our answers help?

Comment: @rayryeng Yes, thank you so much! So sorry I forgot to comment back.

Comment: No worries. When you're ready, go ahead and accept any one of our answers to let the community know you no longer need help. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two problems with the code:

1. You are not accumulating the reconstructed samples properly. Specifically, you are only retaining one value from the resampled signal, not **all** samples.
2. `sinc` in MATLAB uses the normalized sinc function.  This means that you don't have to multiply the argument by `pi`.  Recall that the reconstruction formula requires the normalized sinc function, so there is no multiplication of `pi` in the argument of the function.

Therefore you simply have to change the code inside the `for` loop:

```
F1 = 300e6;
Fs = 800e6;
tmin = 0;
tmax = 10/F1;
t = tmin:1e-12:tmax;
x1 = cos(2*pi*F1*t);
Ts = 1/Fs;
ts = tmin:Ts:tmax;
x1resampled = cos(2*pi*F1*ts);
x1reconstructed = zeros(1,length(t)); %preallocating for speed
samples = length(ts);
for i = 1:1:length(t)
    for n = 1:1:samples
        x1reconstructed(i) = x1reconstructed(i) + x1resampled(n)*sinc((t(i)-n*Ts)/Ts); %%% CHANGE
    end
end
figure(1)
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(t,x1)
hold on
stem(ts,x1resampled)
subplot(2,1,2)
plot(t,x1reconstructed)
```

I now get this plot:

[image]

To make things more efficient, definitely use the `sum` function but do it over all samples.  So your `for` loop should now be:

```
for i = 1:1:length(t)
    x1reconstructed(i) = sum(x1resampled .* sinc((t(i) - (1:samples)*Ts) ./ Ts));
end
```

Answer (score 4):

You can accomplish the same thing, but more efficiently, using the discrete Fourier transform (DFT):

```
F1 = 300e6;
Fs = 800e6;
tmin = 0;
tmax = 10/F1;
t = tmin:1e-12:tmax;
x1 = cos(2*pi*F1*t);
Ts = 1/Fs;
ts = tmin:Ts:tmax;
x1resampled = cos(2*pi*F1*ts);

x1resampledDFT = fftshift(fft(x1resampled));
n = (length(x1)-length(x1resampledDFT))/2;
x1reconstructedDFT = [zeros(1,ceil(n)),x1resampledDFT,zeros(1,floor(n))];
x1reconstructed = ifft(ifftshift(x1reconstructedDFT));
x1reconstructed = x1reconstructed / length(x1resampled) * length(x1reconstructed);

figure(1)
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(t,x1)
hold on
stem(ts,x1resampled)
subplot(2,1,2)
plot(t,x1reconstructed)
```

[image]

What is happening here is that I'm padding the DFT (as computed efficiently using `fft`) with zeros to the desired size. The inverse transform then results in the signal interpolated using the sinc interpolator. To preserve the signal strength some normalization is needed. Any differences you see with Rayryeng's answer is due to the periodic nature of the DFT: basically the sinc functions, as they exit the signal domain on the right, come back in at the left; the data at the right end of the plot influence the result at the left end of the plot and vice versa.

To learn more about interpolation using the Fourier transform, see [this blog post](http://www.crisluengo.net/index.php/archives/619).

Comment: Good job in mentioning the use with the FFT. I didn't mention it because I figured the OP was performing reconstruction as an academic exercise. I also forgot to mention about the periodicity and hence the slight phase shift in the reconstruction.

Comment: @rayryeng Yes, I'm probably not answering the OP's question, but I hope she or someone else learns something new from this. :)